# MYSQL optimizations with mixed and/or

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

We have some large tables and are trying to optimize against. (Note: in this example id, user_id, and delete all have indexes).

These are lightning fast:

```
select *
from sites
where (sites.id = 242 and sites.user_id = 425)

select *
from sites
where (sites.id = 242 or sites.user_id = 425)
```

But once we add any mixed conditional checking it just tanks

```
select *
from sites
where (sites.id = 242 or sites.user_id = 425) and sites.deleted = 1
```

We have found that this query (hack) works, but we are currently using SQLAlchemy for query building and want to avoid any subqueries

```
select *
from sites
where (sites.id = 242 or sites.user_id = 425) and site.id in (
    select id from sites where sites.deleted = 1
)
```

It confuses me that mysql is choking on the mixed case. But is there anyway to optimize this?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried using In? "WHERE sites.deleted = 1 AND sites.id IN(242,425)"

Comment: The first step should be to run an explain plan on the query.  This will generally tell you where the query is hanging up.  That would be useful to post as well, so that we might be able to suggest indexes or optimizations.

Comment: @rontornambe if you recheck the query you will see the 242 and 425 are referring to different fields

Comment: Oops - sorry about that. I agree that examining the query explain plan would be helpful (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)

Comment: Here is the explain: "|  1 | SIMPLE      | sites | ref  | PRIMARY,deleted,user_id | deleted | 1       | const | 719747 | Using where | "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to add a compound index on 
user_id, is_deleted (the order does matter, and I'm not sure which way would be better for this particular scenario).  If you are searching primarily for single or a limited number of user_ids, this order would be the correct way.

That might help you out.

Is ID your unique primary key?  If so, do you need to search for it if it's deleted?

You might be able to use a UNION if that's available, since the primary key search would be very fast.

Brian

Comment: Thanks. We were able to get this optimized by adding a few combo indexes with the `deleted` field.Also in a couple queries we had to `force index()` to make sure the index merge would happen in MySQL